# Rotate through list items per day jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display one list item per day, when the list reaches the end I want it to go to the beginning,  this javascript is what i'm working with.

```
     // Get the number of the week since the epoch.
var day = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1));

i = 0;
// Show one div per day.
$('#postTips li').hide();
$('#postTips li ') + (i = ++i % day)).show();
```

Comment: @velvetlnk : what is your question? . You need to rephrase your query and be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display one list item a day, and display the next the next day:

```
var day = 0, list_items = $('#postTips li'), current_list_item = 0, total_list_item = list_items.length;
function update_list_item() {
    var day_new = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
    if (day_new > day) {
        day = day_new;
        list_items[current_list_item].style.display='none';
        list_items[current_list_item=day%total_list_item].style.display='list-item';
    }
    requestAnimationFrame (update_list_item);
}
list_items.hide ();
update_list_item ();
```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'list_items[current_list_item].hide')

Comment: What do you get if you type `list_items` into the console?

Comment: Make sure you have the list that has id postTips, it is not empty, and the script is in a script tag after postTips.

Comment: if i add the script at the botom in <script> I get this

Comment: TypeError: list_items[current_list_item].hide is not a function. (In 'list_items[current_list_item].hide()', 'list_items[current_list_item].hide' is undefined)

Comment: the html looks like this  <ul id"#postTips"> <li>  <img> <h1>

Comment: It is my fault. I changed the answer. It should work now. Sorry.

Comment: they are all display: none,  I want the first one to show and rotate each day    <li style="display: none;"><li style="display: none;"><li style="display: none;"><li style="display: none;"><li style="display: none;">

Comment: Sorry. I should have typed `list-item` when I typed `list_item` in line 7.

Comment: is this grabbing time form the server , because i'm on my computer (localhost)

Comment: do you know why all <li> are hidden?

Comment: Yes. When you had `list_items[current_list_item=day%total_list_item].style.display='list_item';`, beause `list_item` is not a valid value for `style.display`, `list_items[current_list_item=day%total_list_item].style.display` was not changed. It remained `none`, from `list_items.hide ()`. When you have fixed it, `list-item` is a valid value for `style.display`, so `list_items[current_list_item=day%total_list_item].style.display` is changed to `list-item`. `.style.display='none'` is what is making them hidden.

Comment: ok i changed it to block, I also noticed that it's starting form the middle of the list? any idea why?   does the image change during the day or night?

Comment: If you want to always start with the first list item, use https://jsfiddle.net/8m1kzwad/. The original one starts from the middle because it shows the list item which has the index day%total_list_item, the new one starts from the first because it shows the list item which has the index (day-day_init)%total_item. Where day is the number of days since January 1st, 1970 And the list item changes when you turn to the web page after the day has changed. If you keep the web page in the foreground open during midnight, it will change at midnight.

Comment: If this is the answer you want, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: this is going to go in a phone gap app, I do want the image to change even after the app is closed. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the image is when you are not looking at it, right? The image will not change when the app is closed, but it will change to what it should be once you open it. So I think it is not going to be a problem.